# Cant get push notification from firebase after TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, push-notification, testflight

I have an app that support push notification through firebase.

when I was testing the app on dev it was working and I got push notification, now after I download the app from testFlight the app is working but I can't get push notification. in the developer page of apple

```
developer.apple.com
```

in app IDs and then to my app the push notification tab is enable but then when I press on it I see I have certification only for Development SSL Certificate but not in Production SSL Certificate.

When I try to send notification through the console of firebase im getting faild with the error:

```
 invalid team id key id and apns auth key combination
```

Do you think the problem is there? How can I solve it?

**solution:**

my issue was that I didn't have certification for production in firebase and iTunes connect in push notification I had only for develop

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testflight is a production enviroment, thats why you can't send notifications, you need to change, to

```
Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.sandbox) <---- "MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod"
```

and upload the production certificate to firebase